# How to toggle div by clicking radio button?

Tags: javascript, html

By default the both `reagent_code` should be hidden. By selecting the radio button, have to show the appropriate DIV (following its #id).

```js
function marketer(x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    document.getElementById('reagent_code').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (x == 1) {
    document.getElementById('reagent_code').style.display = 'block';
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="yes" onclick="marketer(1)" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="no" onclick="marketer(0)" value="0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
</div>
```

I get this error.

> TypeError: marketer is not a function

Comment: 1) this doesn't appear to have anything to do with jQuery 2) The error is because the `marketer()` function has not been declared in the correct scope for an `onclick` attribute 2) don't use `on*` event attributes as they are outdated. Use `addEventListener()` when using vanilla JS 3) use the `change` event when working with radios or checkboxes 4) are there multiple elements with an `id` of `reagent_code`? If so that's another issue as they must be unique.

Comment: the function marketer should be defined on global scope, use `window.marketer = function`, if you are defining it inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make sure you do not use the same function names and elements names
2. use an event listener and toggle the element

jQuery

```js
$("[name=marketer]").on("click", function() {
  console.log(this.value)
  $('#reagent_code').toggle(this.value == 1)
})
$("[name=marketer]:checked").click()
```

```css
#Reagent {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" checked id="yes" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="no" value="0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
</div>
<div id="reagent_code">Reagent</div>
```

Plain JS

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("[name=marketer]")].forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.value)
    document.getElementById('reagent_code').style.display = this.value === "0" ? 'none' : 'block';
  })
  if (elem.checked) {
    elem.click();
  }  
})
```

```css
#Reagent { display:none }
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" checked  id="yes" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer"  id="no" value="0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
</div>
<div id="reagent_code">Reagent</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestion of [**AvcS**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5267487/avcs) to your code, without any other library.

> The function marketer should be defined on global scope, use window.marketer = function, if you are defining it inside a function

```js
window.marketer = function(x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    document.getElementById('reagent_code').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (x == 1) {
    document.getElementById('reagent_code').style.display = 'block';
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="yes" onclick="marketer(1)" value="1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="no" onclick="marketer(0)" value="0">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='reagent_code'>
My amazing div
</div>
```

However, as suggested by [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan), you should review your code.

Comment: `    <script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('themes/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('themes/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.js') }}"></script>`  This is my footer and my project is laravel

Comment: Ok, @irankhostravi but the behaviour with your external libraries will be the same.

Comment: No , my problem did not solve and i get error `

    TypeError: marketer is not a function
` again

Comment: I think that you should update/edit your question posting more info, because as you can see, it works. Maybe you have other errors or we haven't some info, you can do it using [SO Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="yes" onclick="marketer(1)" value="1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="marketer" id="no" onclick="marketer(0)" value="0">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
  </div>
  <!-- div to hide and show -->
  <div id="div1" style="display: none;">
      <h1>this is div 1 will show if yes</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" style="display: none;">
      <h1>this is div 2 will show if no</h1>
  </div>
<script>
    function marketer(x) {
          if (x == 0) {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
          } else if (x == 1) {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
            return;
          }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple code below :

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
 if($(this).val() == 'ON') {
  return $('.content').css('display', 'block');
 }
 return $('.content').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" value="ON" checked="">
<label for="radio-1">ON</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2" value="OFF">
<label for="radio-2">OFF</label>

<div class="content">
 Hello world.
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```